# Replication not working? Trying to fix after someone else did it

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

Basically I have taken over out domain for someone else. They were in the middle of upgrading to Windows Server 2016 from 2012 for AD. Problem is the old AD server is still running, so essentially we have 2 DC's right now, the upgrade was never completed. From what I can tell, both servers are GC's, and both servers are running DNS and group policy. DHCP is only on new server. FSMO roles are showing on new server. However, replication does not seem to be working, the new server does not have SYSVOL or NETLOGON folders. When I force a replication, there are no errors but it is definitely not working. Running a DCDIAG says the new server is not advertising. I am fairly new to this, other than classes and books, so I am not sure where he left off or has left to do. I would start from scratch but the new server seems to have most of the work done. I have looked at forums and have tried some troubleshooting, dcdiag and such but I am not seeing any errors, besides the not advertising and all the solutions for that do not apply to my situation. These are both virtual in a VMWARE environment. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should hire a professional or a friend to come in and assist and help you learn. There are numerous articles online with detailed steps to troubleshoot replication. We’re certainly not going to be able to solve your problem in a Q & A forum based on the little information you provided.

Comment: `I would start from scratch but the new server seems to have most of the work done` - Well... it isn't working so I see no value in spending a lot of time troubleshooting this. Move DHCP back to the previous DC, transfer or seize the FSMO roles back to the previous DC, DCPROMO the new DC to demote it, and start from scratch with the new DC.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to verify the DFS Replication health between the servers, by following this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2958414 :

> **Symptoms**
>
> You may encounter a situation in which SYSVOL and Netlogon shares are
>   not shared on a domain controller. The following additional symptoms
>   or conditions may also apply:
>
> - The SYSVOL folder is empty.
> - The affected domain controller was recently promoted.
> - The environment contains domain controllers running versions of Windows earlier than Windows Server 2012 R2.
> - DFS Replication is used to replicate the SYSVOL Share replicated folder.
> - An upstream domain controller's DFS Replication service is in an error state.
>
> **Cause**
>
> Domain controllers without SYSVOL shared cannot replicate inbound
>   because of upstream (source) domain controllers being in an error
>   state. Frequently (but not limited to), the upstream servers have
>   stopped replication because of a dirty shutdown (event ID 2213).

According to the tutorials I have read, the Active Directory replication subsystem does not handle synchronization of SYSVOL and NETLOGON folder contents between domain controllers. Instead, it handles topology discovery (KCC, ISTG) and synchronization of changes committed against the LDAP databases. Replication of SYSVOL and NETLOGON shares are handled by either FRS (File Replication Service) or DFS-R (Distributed File System Replication) subsystem.